# File Uploaded but not shown in the Firebase realtime database - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

In my android app when I am uploading a PDF file it's uploaded in the firebase storage but the file name and url is not shown in the realtime database.

```
 private void uploadPDFFile(Uri data) {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StorageReference reference = storageReference.child("uploads/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf");
    reference.putFile(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



                    Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    while(!uri.isComplete());
                    Uri url = uri.getResult();

                    uploadPDF uploadPDF = new uploadPDF(editPDFName.getText().toString(),url.toString());
                    databaseReference.child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(uploadPDF);



                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded: " + (int) progress + "%");

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this please:

```
while(!uri.isComplete());
```

Even if it works, it's a tight loop consuming more resources than needed.

Instead follow the pattern shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url):

```
reference.putFile(data)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


            Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            uriTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Uri url = uriTask.getResult();

                    uploadPDF uploadPDF = new uploadPDF(editPDFName.getText().toString(),url.toString());
                    databaseReference.child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(uploadPDF);


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(
```