# Crash when running collectionGroup query in Cloud Firestore (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I run a mobile app project using Swift, SwiftUI and Cloud Firestore where I need to find users based on their different settings/preferences. I have solved this by using a collectionGroup query. But sometimes (maybe 1 out of 10 times) the query crashes without any (for me) understandable error message. The composite indexes have been created using the http links provided from XCode.

This is the function I use:

```
func getUsersFromActivityPrefs(genders:[String], activities:[Int],skillScore_min:Int, skillScore_max:Int,completion:@escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
   
var matchUsers = [String]()
var count = 0
let db = Firestore.firestore()

for gender in genders {
    for activity in activities {
        let dbRef = db.collectionGroup("activity_preferences")
            .whereField("gender", isEqualTo: gender)
            .whereField("activityid", isEqualTo: activity)
            .whereField("status", isEqualTo: true)
            .whereField("skill_score", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: skillScore_min)
            .whereField("skill_score", isLessThanOrEqualTo: skillScore_max)
            .limit(to: 100)
        dbRef.getDocuments {( snap, err) in
            count+=1
            if err != nil {
                print(err!.localizedDescription)
            }
            for i in snap!.documentChanges{
                let uid = i.document.get("uid") as? String ?? ""
                if uid != "" && !matchUsers.contains(uid) {
                    matchUsers.append(uid)
                    if matchUsers.count == 100 {
                        count = genders.count * activities.count
                        completion(matchUsers) //escaping completion handler
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            if count == genders.count * activities.count {
                completion(matchUsers)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have attached the trace log and the crash message from XCode. Im using the latest version of Firebase SDK and deployment target is iOS14.
This is the trace log I get:

thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4f)
frame #0: 0x00007fff4b80dd66 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 322 frame #1: 0x00007fff4b81f1a5 AttributeGraph`AGGraphGetValue + 203
frame #2: 0x00007fff55e7ffab SwiftUI`SwiftUI.DynamicBody.phase.getter : SwiftUI._GraphInputs.Phase + 27 frame #3: 0x00007fff55e80176 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.DynamicBody.updateValue() -> () + 294
frame #4: 0x00007fff55b9583a SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for implicit closure #2 (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in implicit closure #1 (A1.Type) -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 () -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafePointer<A1>) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<A> in AttributeGraph.Attribute.init<A where A == A1.Value, A1: AttributeGraph.StatefulRule>(A1) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<A> + 26 frame #5: 0x00007fff4b808d03 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 505
frame #6: 0x00007fff4b809199 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 335 frame #7: 0x00007fff4b80d8e8 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*) + 130
frame #8: 0x00007fff4b81f1f3 AttributeGraph`AGGraphGetValue + 281 frame #9: 0x00007fff561aeeb7 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.GraphHost.updatePreferences() -> Swift.Bool + 39
frame #10: 0x00007fff55c9a8cf SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at: SwiftUI.Time) -> () + 95 frame #11: 0x00007fff5611310c SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> () + 1308
frame #12: 0x00007fff56112327 SwiftUI`(extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> () + 343 frame #13: 0x00007fff55ba07de SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI._UIHostingView.requestImmediateUpdate() -> () + 62
frame #14: 0x00007fff562739ae SwiftUI`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> () + 14 frame #15: 0x0000000112ebd8ac libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
frame #16: 0x0000000112ebea88 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8 frame #17: 0x0000000112eccf23 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1152
frame #18: 0x00007fff203a8276 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9 frame #19: 0x00007fff203a2b06 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2685
frame #20: 0x00007fff203a1b9e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567 frame #21: 0x00007fff2b773db3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 139
frame #22: 0x00007fff24660af3 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 912 frame #23: 0x00007fff24665a04 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 101
frame #24: 0x000000010db84a5b Sparring`main at AppDelegate.swift:14:7 frame #25: 0x00007fff20257415 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Attachments:
Crash in XCode [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOtag.jpg)
Composite index [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMJYv.png)

Comment: It appears you're using SwiftUI? That seems to be related to the error, not the code in the question. Also, generally speaking, Firebase does not like to be run in tight loops - you've got two of them so there may be something there. You might consider isolating the issue a bit further since it's intermittent - add some print statements and/or breaks and step through the code until it crashes to try to narrow the issue.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I have isolated the crash to the getDocuments line. I.e. it never enters the return closure. Is there some way to avoid the two loops? The use of whereField statements in Firebase is very limited when they are just in combinations (like OR).

Comment: @Jay can you point to something that says to avoid network operations in loops?

Comment: @bsod Probably not as that's not what was stated :-) UI calls in Firebase closures are on the main thread and this appears to be SwiftUI. We don't know where this was called from or how it's affecting the UI but it does appear to be related to SwiftUI. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513101/oncompletelistener-is-not-called-for-setvalue-in-realtimedatabase/46513256#46513256) along with [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823096/file-uploaded-but-not-shown-in-the-firebase-realtime-database-android-studio/56824363#56824363). All guesswork atm.

Comment: @Jay those concern RTDB. Firestore is a different animal and I haven't seen any problems looping network operations with it, especially the small number that OP is doing. The bad access error suggests the closure is accessing something that's been prematurely deallocated or the closure itself is missing. I couldn't reproduce the error so I think you're right that the problem is something outside of this code.

Comment: @bsod, I dont understand. If the error is outside this code, I should be able to get the execution to stop at the completion(matchUsers) row if I have a breakpoint there? I have added print commands before the "dbRef.getDocuments" line and on the first line inside the closure (count+=1) and the crash always occurs before count+= 1 is reached but after dbRef is set. Please elaborate.

Comment: @bsod I agree, they are RTDB but I didn't say anything about looping network operations - those are easy as they all run on background threads. The UI is usually the issue as tight loops don't give the closures enough time to update the UI without having it stutter or do other weird things - like in this case. I am not saying it's this code, it *may* be but it's odd the firebase closure isnt being called.

Comment: That code, as it should not be crashing. Can you update your question with your *current* code and let us know if it's the same crash?

Answer (score 0):

```
func getUsersFromActivityPrefs(genders: [String], activities: [Int], skillScore_min: Int, skillScore_max: Int, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    var matchUsers = [String]()
    var count = 0
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup() // instantiate dispatch group outside loop
    
    for gender in genders {
        for activity in activities {
            dispatch.enter() // enter group on each iteration
            
            let dbRef = db.collectionGroup("activity_preferences")
                .whereField("gender", isEqualTo: gender)
                .whereField("activityid", isEqualTo: activity)
                .whereField("status", isEqualTo: true)
                .whereField("skill_score", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: skillScore_min)
                .whereField("skill_score", isLessThanOrEqualTo: skillScore_max)
                .limit(to: 100)
            
            dbRef.getDocuments {( snap, err) in
                if let snap = snap {
                    count += 1
                    
                    for doc in snap.documents {
                        if let uid = doc.get("uid") as? String,
                           !matchUsers.contains(uid) {
                            matchUsers.append(uid)
                        }
                    }
                } else if let err = err {
                    print(err)
                }
                
                dispatch.leave() // always leave no matter what the db returned
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*
     this is the group's completion handler and it's only
     called once after all groups have entered and left
     */
    dispatch.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(matchUsers)
    }
}
```

Comment: That code seems to work fine :) : So is the issue related to that I have two completion() returns?

Comment: @Nikodym and what happens when you run this?

Comment: I get "sucess" prints

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same crash error with your modified code.

Comment: @Nikodym then your problem is how you handle the completion and I suspect it's the competing calls. The fix is simple but I can't tell from your code what exactly you want to happen. You limit your query to 100 results but only deal with document changes (why?) and you check if the array count is 100 (why?). What's the plan with this document grab?

Comment: Im actually interested in all documents so I guess I should change this to "for document in snap!.documents {}. The reason for checking the array count is that the query can return the same user in different loops so I need to count the unique users resulting from all loops. But I will test to move the second completion inside the for loop:

Comment: @Nikodym I made another edit. I'd suggest this as your template. Get the documents, handle them, and then call completion one time after all the work is complete. Also, you should consider always calling completion, even if a snapshot wasn't returned and there was an error—return `nil` if you have to, just return something (consider returning a `Result` object, perhaps). The caller (of this function) should always expect some sort of response so the general flow of work always keeps moving.

Comment: @Nikodym what you can do, which may be a better solution, is to run both of the loops and then call completion one time after they've both finished. Additionally, if you're worried about duplicate users, you can change from array containers to set containers. But if you simply run both queries first and then merge the arrays together (filtering out duplicates), you can run completion one time and simplify things greatly.

Comment: thanks for you help. But I dont understand how your suggestion of having the completion(matchUsers) statement inside the first for loop can return all documents from the two loops. Will the function not escape as soon as completion is called the first time in the loops and thereby missing out on the remaining documents from the other loops?

Comment: @Nikodym I updated my answer to reflect my suggestion. Using a dispatch group, you can make any number of network requests and give them a single completion handler.

Comment: Yes, this is nice. But I need to modify it so I exit when the arrray count has reached 100. But I have now identified why the app crashed. It was as you said, outside this code. But still somewhat strange that it could crash before the completion handler has executed